# Resizing a software RAID remotely, no LVM, / partition

Tags: raid, mdadm, ext4

I have a server that has a software RAID **without** LVM. That is only `mdadm`.

There are the partitions `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sdb2` which form `/dev/md2`.

There is also a lot of space **after** both `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sdb2` (almost 2TB)

What I want to do is resize `/dev/md2` and take up all the space that is on the right of those to partitions.

The bad part is that `/dev/md2` is my `/` mount, so I can do things only via rescue-pro mode (OVH server).

Is there a way to resize `/dev/md2`? If "yes", how?

By the way, the partitions are EXT4.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53400/resize-non-lvm-ext4-root-partition

Comment: @gtirloni So, that would be (in parted) `rm 2`, `mkpart primary <statrt> <new end>`. Reboot. `e2fsck -f /dev/sda2` then `resize2fs /dev/sda2`. And that for `sdb2`. ?

Comment: Don't fsck a component of a working raid device! Resize both component partitions first, then (after reboot) run "mdadm --grow --size=max /dev/md2", _then_ you can resize2fs /dev/md2 (fsck is not needed when doing an online resize to a larger size).

Comment: @wurtel There is a problem. I can't `modprome md` in the rescue-pro mode in OVH. Can I run `mdadm --grow --size=max /dev/md2` while running the OS? (md2 contains my `/`)

Comment: Running mdadm --grow on an active device is not a problem in my experience. I've done that on active webservers remotely in the past.

Comment: @wurtel Great! One last question: If I have 2 partitions and part 1 starts at 50s and ends at 300s and part 2 starts at 800s and ends at 1000s, what should I type for <end> in "mkpart primary 50 <end>" to fill up the entire space between the 2 partitions without overlapping the part 2? 800 or 799?  (s == sectors)

Comment: Hmm, not my area of expertise, I usually use fdisk which handles these details for me. I would choose 799 just to be safe.

Comment: @wurtel I just resized both partitions and then rebooted, but now my server isn't going up, so I went to rescue mode again and did "print all" in parted and now I see my partitions with the right size, but there is no `/dev/md2`, instead there is `/dev/md3`! Why did it change it's name and how do I rename it?

Comment: Check the answer to [this] [1] question.

  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/346719/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-md-device-mdadm